# Gnome ubuntu - always display alt hud

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I have recently installed gnome ubuntu 16.04 LTS. In an application, like firefox for example, if i press alt i get a menu that has file, edit etc, which shows just above my firefox tab. Is it possible in gnome to make that appear as deafault, instead of having to press alt for it to appear?

Comment: For Firefox you can just right click on the empty space in tab-bar and select the checkbox next to **Menu Bar**.

Comment: ok thanks, but for example when I use nylas mail I need to press alt for it to come, and there may be other applications. It would be good if there is a way of having is enabled already, maybe a bit like how unity always has it at the top (though I would rather it be enabled automatically in the window rather than on the bar on top)